# How add a css id selector to a views row

Tags: views, theming

I need to add a css id selector to a views row. Of course this is straight forward with a class selector such as `.my-class` but how do I insert something like `#my-class` at the individual row level?

I realize that this probably invalid CSS; however, the ID appears to be needed to trigger some JavaScript.

Some background: I want to use a component from the Bourbon Refills CSS  framework for a 'fade in' effect and apply this to all the rows in a views. See http://refills.bourbon.io/components/#fade-in.

In order the make this work I need to add a CSS ID `#js-fadeInElement` to each row.

#### Note

After a bit more digging, it seems I may need a custom `row.tpl` file in my theme. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

No need to add ID for each row, you can achieve it by each row CSS class it self. Instead of `document.getElementById("js-fadeInElement");` you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("js-fadeInElement");`

**Solution 2:**

1. You can use Views theme templates to modify the HTML output and add your id attribute.
2. Under the Advanced section, you will find Theme: information.

> This link will show you possible file name for templates and a sample
>   content of that file.

3. You probably want to copy and modify the "Style output". You can put your custom template in your own theme directory. You probably want a name like `views-view-list--your-view--page.tpl.php`

Please follow this [link](http://www.group42.ca/theming_views_2_the_basics) to override the template.

Comment: Just an addition: In your view, you can easily find the exact name you need   for the template by going to Advanced > Theme Information .